# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape. Image to follow my face

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, facial-identification

I am trying to overlay an image like a mask over my face using cv2 that follows live on recording. At the moment I am getting this error. I understand about layers or that I am trying to do a 2d on 3d but I can't find this specifically for my case any help is helpful thank you

This is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Camera/Projects/Camera.py", line 33, in <module>
    display[ y:y+img_height , x:x+img_width ] = mask
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (288,347,3) into shape (118,347,3)
```

This is the code:

```
import cv2, time

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('Data//haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check, display= video.read()

scale_percent=150

#Scaling Calculations
width = int(display.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(display.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dsize = (width, height)

mask = cv2.imread(r"Data//image.png")



img_height, img_width, _ = mask.shape



while True:
    #Take image from cam
    check, display= video.read()
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(display, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    
    
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        display[ y:y+img_height , x:x+img_width ] = mask
        #cv2.rectangle(display, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)   # code for a box that follows my face(this works)
    
    
    #Rescale with the scaling
    output = cv2.resize(display, dsize) 
    cv2.imshow("Capture", output)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    
    if key == ord('q'):
        break


video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: question lacks a complete traceback, and the error message is truncated too.. please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Check `cv2.addWeighted`.  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html

Comment: Time Roberts I tried it, however add weighted doesn't allow me to choose a certain location to put the image over